# Get header by name from Message request headers

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

How can I get a header from a Message request object? I don't want to iterate through the Headers to find the header needed. Can I do something like `.get('auth')`?

```
public class MessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var headers = request.Headers;
        return null;
    }
// ...
```

Comment: Are you looking for SOAP headers, or HTTP headers? If HTTP, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18970405/6741868) could help you, otherwise look into [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444901/6741868).